# Serilog Crashed if we set Minimum log level to DEBUG(All Caps)

Tags: serilog

**Description**
Serilog Crashed if we set Minimum log level to `DEBUG` (All Caps)

**Reproduction**

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
"Default": "DEBUG",
```

**Expected behavior**
No exception should throw if we provide a log level in Caps

**Relevant package, tooling and runtime versions**

`serilog.aspnetcore` v `4.1.0`

**Additional context**

Exception: `The value DEBUG is not a valid Serilog level.`

Stack:

> at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.ParseLogEventLevel(String value)
> at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.<ApplyMinimumLevel>g__ApplyMinimumLevel|9_1(IConfigurationSection directive, Action`2 applyConfigAction, <>c__DisplayClass9_0& )
> at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.ApplyMinimumLevel(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
> at Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.Configure(LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration)
> at Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration.Settings(ILoggerSettings settings)
> at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, String sectionName, DependencyContext dependencyContext)
> at Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Configuration(LoggerSettingsConfiguration settingConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration, DependencyContext dependencyContext)

Link: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1661

Serilog log levels are Case sensitive?

Comment: Are there other parts of the config file that do not need to be case sensitive (is this truly the only part of the config file that is not case-sensitive, are there other enums that are not case sensitive)? Is the exception unclear?